# Complexity of Maximum Entropy Algorithm in Sentiment Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-entropy, sentiment-analysis

Does anyone know how the process of calculating the complexity of the maximum entropy algorithm and its implementation later in the sentiment analysis?
Please help me, because I haven't got a reference regarding that matter..
Thank you